# How to bind JSON to model within a method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

I understand that MVC4 can automatically bind json to type models.

For example, take an **HTMLItem** model.

In part of a method I retrieve the **HTMLItem** model data in json format from an external site using HttpRequest and StreamReader. I grab this as a string and then want to pass it into another method that takes HTMLItem as a parameter.

How do I ensure that the receiving method handles this as the type I require (**HTMLItem**)?  It currently doesn't recognise it as such.

I tried assigning the string to the model in the originating method, but the IDE gives me the red squiggly for assigning a string to another type.

I don't want to have to go through the json string  and assign each field manually if possible.

Any help, as always, much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deserialize the JSON to your model like:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
...

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
YourModelType model = serializer.Deserialize<YourModelType>(yourJSON);
```